# Undefined Variable Header in PHP SEND MAIL

Tags: php, sql, php-5.3, php-5.5

After my user registers, I want them to receive an email from my local host server which I'm running. The same script below works fine on a paid hosting but when I try to run it on my local host I get the following error:

> NOTE: Undefined Variable: Headers in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site/newuser.php on line 60

```
else {

echo "<br /><center>** CHECK SPAM **. We have sent a activation code to your email,
 you will not be able to login follow the steps.</center>";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = sha1(md5($_POST['password']));
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cwid = $_POST['cwid'];

$verificationCode = md5(uniqid($_POST['name'], true));

(LINE 60) $headers .= "Reply-To: Kwame Project<d1kwame@gmail.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: Kwame Project<d1kwame@gmail.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: Kwame Project<d1kwame@gmail.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Organization: Kwame\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";

$message = "Hello " . $name . "! It appears you have registed an 
account with us.\r\nIn order to complete your registration, you must 
click the link below.\r\n" . $siteURL . "activate.php?
code=".$verificationCode."\r\nThank you!";

$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

mail($email, 'Activate Your Account', $message, $headers);



$InsertUser = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO students (`cwid`, `name`,     
`password`, `activated`, `activation_code`, `email`, `user_group`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$InsertUser->execute(array($cwid, $name, $password, 0,   
$verificationCode, $email, 0));

header('Refresh: 3; url=login.php');
}


}
```

Comment: What happens when you change line 60 from `$headers .= ...` to `$headers = ...`?

Comment: Are we missing some code?

Comment: No, that is all the code pertaining that part of the if else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize your $headers variable before line 60 :

```
$headers = '';
```

Comment: How ? Please give me an example

Comment: see my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
...........
$headers = '';
(LINE 60) $headers .= "Reply-To: Kwame Project<d1kwame@gmail.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: Kwame Project<d1kwame@gmail.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: Kwame Project<d1kwame@gmail.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Organization: Kwame\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";

$message = "Hello " . $name . "! It appears you have registed an 
account with us.\r\nIn order to complete your registration, you must 
click the link below.\r\n" . $siteURL . "activate.php?
code=".$verificationCode."\r\nThank you!";

$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

mail($email, 'Activate Your Account', $message, $headers);



$InsertUser = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO students (`cwid`, `name`,     
`password`, `activated`, `activation_code`, `email`, `user_group`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$InsertUser->execute(array($cwid, $name, $password, 0,   
$verificationCode, $email, 0));

header('Refresh: 3; url=login.php');
```